# Shipping Method does not inherit settings from the class

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a custom shipping method that must start as not enabled when installed.

My shipping method class extends WC_Shipping_Method:

```
public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {

    ...
    $this->instance_id        = absint( $instance_id );
    $this->supports = array(
        'shipping-zones',
        'instance-settings',
        'settings'
    );
    ...
    $this-init();
    $this->enabled = isset( $this->settings['enabled'] ) ? $this->settings['enabled'] : 'no';
}

function init() {

    $this->init_form_fields();
    $this->init_settings();
    ...
    $this->init_instance_settings();
    ...
}
```

The setting is saved, and the variable `$this->enabled` is `'no'` inside both __construct() and init().

The shipping method is only available in a very specific area, so the plugin is generating a shipping zone on activation that includes the shipping method.

```
$new_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone();
$new_zone->set_zone_name( $zone_name );
$new_zone->add_location( ... );
$new_zone->add_shipping_method( ... );
$new_zone->save();
```

This instance of the shipping method always have `$this->enabled` set to `'yes'`.

There must be something i do not understand regarding instances and settings here.

Any idea how I can have the zone-specific instance inherit the main shipping method settings?

Comment: where do you see that the shipping method is enabled ? in the code on the shipping zone creation ? or in the backend on the pages of shipping configuration ?

Comment: I just used a `var_dump()` inside `init()` and `__construct()`. The class was invoked inside a product page.

Comment: I have found, the enabled status of the shipping zone is not linked at the `enabled` attribut in the instance. to set it to disabled on generation, you have to disabled it in the database https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.4.3/includes/class-wc-ajax.php#L2628